# DataContractSerializer problem with events/delegate fields

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, serialization

On my WPF application, I am using `DataContractSerializer` to serialize object. I observed that it fails to serialize the types that has got an event or delegate declaration. Consider the following failing code:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DerivedClass derivedClass = new DerivedClass {Name = "Test", Age = 10};
        derivedClass.PropertyChanged += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("hello");

        DataContractSerializer serializer  = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DerivedClass));
        using(FileStream stream = new FileStream("c:\\test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, derivedClass);
        }     
    }
}
```

This fails with message

> Type
>   'System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry'
>   with data contract name
>   'DelegateSerializationHolder.DelegateEntry:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System'
>   is not expected. Add any types not
>   known statically to the list of known
>   types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them to the list of known types
>   passed to DataContractSerializer.

I tried to add attributes like `[DataMember(IsRequired = false)]` on the event to indicate that it should not be serialized, but nothing worked.

Everything worked when I removed the `[Serializable]` attribute from the `BaseClass`. I am wondering why this behavior? Is it safe to avoid giving `[Serializable]` attribute?

.NET framework version : 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[field:NonSerialized]
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

This tells the `DataContractSerializer`, "don't serialize the auto-generated `EventHandlerList` field for this event". Thus, any object instances attached to your event won't be considered part of the object graph being serialized.