# Mark Event as NonSerializable for DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, events, datacontractserializer

I have the following Event in my implementation of RelayCommand:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
  add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
  remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

Now I'm using `DataContractSerializer`. I know when using `DataContractSerializer` all Events have to be marked as `[field:NonSerialized]`. But in this case this doesn't work because my `CanExecuteChanged` Event is just a property with no private field.

How can I mark this property as `NonSerializable`?

**EDIT:**

Here is the whole RelayCommand class:

```
[DataContract]
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{

  [field:NonSerialized]
  readonly Action<object> _execute;

  [field:NonSerialized]
  readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

  public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
    : this(execute, null)
  {
  }

  public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
  {
    if (execute == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;
  }

  [DebuggerStepThrough]
  public bool CanExecute(object parameters)
  {
    return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameters);
  }

  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
  }

  public void Execute(object parameters)
  {
    _execute(parameters);
  }
}
```

When I try to execute the `DataContractSerializer` I'm getting the following error:

> Type 'MyNamespace.RelayCommand' with data contract name 'RelayCommand:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Comment: as you have said, it is not a field, so it never be serialized. why do you think it will?

Comment: and as I remember, the `DataContractSerializer` will only serialize fields/properties which are marked as `DataMember`

Comment: I think I have the same situation like in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3476595/1384848
I'm getting the same error message when I try to serialize with the `DataContractSerializer` so I tried the solution what was given there, but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: I've just used the sample from the [link you gave](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3476595/1384848), but I've replaced the `PropertyChanged` event with your `CanExecuteChanged` event. it works without problem, please check that you have not other events.

Comment: Ok, how did you replace the `PropertyChanged` event with my `CanExecuteChanged` event? The `PropertyChanged` event in the example does not use the add/remove accessors like my event does and so it is possible to add the `[field:NonSerialized]` Attribute to the `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: I've added the new answer where I show how I did replaced the `PropertyChanged` with the `CanExecuteChanged`

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've edited my question and and added my `RelayCommand` class. I can't find any error - maybe you can. :)

Comment: 1. The exception you've wrote is absolutely not related to the event serialization.

Comment: 2. Why do you want to serialize `RelayCommand`?

Comment: 3. The `DataContractSerializer` has the overloaded constructor with the second argument `knownTypes` you should pass there for example `new[] { typeof(RelayCommand) }`

Comment: @ie. 3. worked fine - Many thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

That is how I've updated the sample from the [link you gave me in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476595/datacontractserializer-problem-with-events-delegate-fields):

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var derivedClass = new DerivedClass { Name = "Test", Age = 10 };
        derivedClass.CanExecuteChanged += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("hello");

        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DerivedClass));
        using (var stream = new FileStream("d:\\test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, derivedClass);
        }
    }
}
```

It works without any exception.